# Quadratic variation of linear combination of two processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

Suppose I have two process $X_t:=\int_0^t f(X_s,s)dB_s$ and $Y_t:=\int_0^t g(Y_s,s)dB_s$. Let both $g,f$ be continuously differentiable functions. I am aware of the result that implies that the corresponding quadratic variations are given by $[X]_t=\int_0^tf^2(x,s)ds$ and $[Y]_t=\int_0^tg^2(x,s)ds$.

I am interested in a linear combination of a Bernouilli variable $W$ (known at $t=0$) and these processes, and want to calculate the quadratic variation of the process $WX_t + (1-W)Y_t$. I do not know much about $[X,Y]_t$ (the covariation). Is it still possible to compute the quadratic variation I am intersted in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "Bernouilli variable," you mean that $W$ is either $1$ or $0$, right?

Comment: Yes! @user6247850

Answer (score 1):

Since either $W = 0$ or $W = 1$, $Z_t := W X_t + (1-W)Y_t$ will either equal $X_t$ or $Y_t$ for all $t$.  Hence $[Z]_t = W [X]_t + (1-W)[Y]_t$.

This could be verified by checking that $Z_t^2 - [Z]_t$ is a local martingale, or by applying the result that $[A+B]_t = [A]_t+[B]_t + 2 [A,B]_t$ for any processes $A,B$ to $A=WX$ and $B=(1-W)Y$ (and using that $W(1-W)=0$ to get $[WX,(1-W)Y]_t=0$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The only thing I am not being able to convince myself is that $[WX]_t=W[X]_t$. I mean, does it make sense for the quadratic variation to be a random variable? I mean $WX_t$ is a perfectly fine stochatic process, and its quadratic variations aren't random variables..

Comment: Yes, the quadratic variation can definitely be a random process.  I think the quadratic variation of $W X_t$ is $W [X]_t$, which is also a random variable.

Comment: May I ask you, is the quadratic variation of $X_t$ itself a stochastic process as well (in our case)?

Comment: After looking at it again, yes, I think the quadratic variation of $X_t = \int_0^t f(X_s,s)dB_s$ is $[X]_t = \int_0^t f(X_s,s)^2ds$.